# Unable to reach the proper tables in Postgres from Node using node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pgadmin, node-postgres

I'm trying to connect to postgres from Node using `node-postgres`, but even though the authentication is granted, I'm unable to search reach the tables.  For example, when I perform:

```js
const { Client } = require('pg')
const client = new Client({
    user: 'username',
    password: 'somepassword',
    host: 'hostinfo',
    port: '5432',
    database: 'databaseInfo',
    ssl: true,
})

const execute = async() => {
    try {
        await client.connect()
        await client.query("BEGIN")
        const results = await client.query("select * from User")
        await client.query("COMMIT")
        console.log(results.rows)
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    } finally {
        await client.end()
        console.log("Finished")
    }
}

execute()
```

it returns the User of the database, which is the 'username' that I used to access the database, not the content of the `User` table.

If I were to search for any other tables in the database, say the `Review` table, the error message shows

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error: relation "review" does
>   not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is really named "User" (with a capital "U"), you should be quoting its name when querying, like this:

```
const results = await client.query('select * from "User"')
```

When unquoted, PostgreSQL will think you're calling the function alias `user`, which is the same as `current_user`.

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS